# How to define more line types for graphs in R (custom linetype)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

There are 6 line types defined for plots in R defined as "dashed", "longdash" ... [Link](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Shapes_and_line_types/)

How can I define more types if I have more that 6 series to plot ? The graph lines can be distinguished based on colour in the soft copy but is not suitable for black and white printing.

Are there more options available or do I need to define them based on combining lines and points as in the reference link?

```
plot(x, type = "b", pch = 0, lty = "dotted")
```

Some google search suggested that patterns of on/off can also be specified with strings of 2, 4, 6, or 8 characters (non-zero hexadecimal characters, 1–9 and a–f) and the pre-set styles are “dashed” = “44", “dotted” = “13”, “dotdash” = “1343”, “longdash” = “73”, “twodash” = “2262”.

But seems it will be a lot of hit and trial to use this to define new line types which will be distinguishable on B&W printing.

## Edit :

If points and line styles are combined, how can I define the set of line types in such a way that they can be input as

```
plot(DF, ..., col = 1:ncol(DF), lty = 1:ncol(DF))
# where DF is the set of data to be plotted.
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: One alternative I often see in b/w graphs is to use different markers like triangles, squares, circles, plusses, asterisks, open circles along with the dotdash or dotted style.

Comment: Yes, I added that in the code where pch is the style of points used. I am wondering if there is an alternative which works both in colour and b/w in the way mentioned.

Answer (score 19):

As you have mentioned in your link, legal values are the strings "blank", "solid", "dashed", "dotted", "dotdash", "longdash", and "twodash". Alternatively, the numbers 0 to 6 can be used (0 for "blank", 1 for "solid", ...).

**Moreover**, one can also use strings that define the linetype with up to **8 hexadecimal digits** (each digit specifying the length of interleaved lines and gaps).

Here an example , using `linetype` aes in `ggplot2` equivalent to `lty` in base R. This way you can get more than the 6 predefined types.

```
library(ggplot2)
d=data.frame(lt=c("blank", "solid", "dashed", "dotted", 
                  "dotdash", "longdash", "twodash", "1F", 
                  "F1", "4C88C488", "12345678"))
ggplot() +
  scale_x_continuous(name="", limits=c(0,1), breaks=NULL) +
  scale_y_discrete(name="linetype") +
  scale_linetype_identity() +
  geom_segment(data=d, mapping=aes(x=0, xend=1, y=lt, yend=lt, linetype=lt))
```

[image]

Explanation:

```
"1F": dash length 1, gap length F (15)
"F1": dash length F (15), gap length 1
"4C88C488": dash (4), gap (C=12), dash (8), gap (8), dash (C=12), ...
"12345678": dash (1), gap (2), dash (3), gap (4), ...
```

PS: the solution is adopted from this [link](http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/linetype).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Will the lines twodash and 12345678 be different on print ?Theoritically, there are many combinations of 8 digits but will they be visually different?  If I have to define using points, is there a way to create a vector of line types and color also maybe ?

Comment: if you want to use `points` better to use `pch` parameter you have 0:18 symboles and also you can use some character to specify points something like pch="a".

Comment: Can I create a vector of line types which I can then use as lty = 1:N? How do I define this vector using pch ?

Comment: Huh, I like the `"1F"` and `"F1"` solution a lot.... Gives so much possibilities!

Answer (score 0):

This works using pch = 1:ncol(DF)

```
# sample data
dat <- matrix(runif(40,1,20),ncol=10) 
matplot(dat, type = "b", lty = "longdash", pch = 1:10, col = 1:10, lwd = 2)
```