# More variation in line types in R (add dots, plusses...)

Tags: r, plot, graph, linear-regression

I'm plotting several regression lines in one graph in R. I use the `lty=` setting in `abline()` to distinguish them. However, I find this quite unsatisfying once I have more than three lines: all the [line types](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Shapes_and_line_types/) look too similar. (My graph needs to be black/white. )

I was sure there must be a way of combining symbols and lines in R (to have a dashed line with no symbols, one with crosses, etc.), but could not figure it out, at least for `abline()`. I'm basically thinking combining the symbols in [pch](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/images/points.png) with line types or more interesting lines like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weather_front#/media/File:NWS_weather_fronts.svg).

- Is there a way to create new line types? (like for `pch`, where one
  can just type in characters)?
- Are there other ways to make lines more easily distinguishable?
- Or do I have to switch to ggplot, or other packages?

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788945/how-to-define-more-line-types-for-graphs-in-r) goes into defining the details of line types, but did not really help me here...

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying you want to define a line consisting of plus signs or other characters?

Comment: @RyanThompson guess I was not really clear on that, added details above... ("I'm basically thinking combining the symbols in [pch](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/images/points.png) with line types or more interesting lines like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weather_front#/media/File:NWS_weather_fronts.svg)"

Comment: @rawr i would line types that are easily distinguishable. the 8^8, is that based on using hex #s? Or am I missing sth?

Comment: @patrick you said create new line types which that question you linked explains it. you can add points on top of each line but not with abline. the r cookbook link you posted shows that--using different pch for line types

Comment: One differentiation is to use lwd to mess with the width.

Comment: thanks @lmo, that's a nice idea. @rawr: it shows how to use `pch` with `points ()`, but if I feed a `pch=` setting into my `abline()`, it just ignores me without further comment.

Comment: ... which is perhaps why @rawr said *"but not with abline"*. Can you not use `lines`? You'll have to define exactly where you want the dots/symbols, but lacking changing the substructure of the line types (`lty`) in R, there is not a mechanism in base graphics for intuiting where you want to overlay your symbols on your line. The "hard part" of such a function is to generically and effectively determine symbol and line spacing when you don't control the user coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it by utilising `predict` to break up the `abline` into segments, that you can then specify a `pch=` against. By manually specifying points, you can decide how often you want a custom tick mark in the `length.out=` argument:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- jitter(x,5)
fit <- lm(y~x)
plot(x,y)

pts <- seq(min(x),max(x),length.out=10)
lines(pts, predict(fit, list(x=pts)), type="o", pch="^")
```

[image]