# big dotted geom_line, but dots closer together

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am curious if it is possible to increase the size of dots on a dotted line within geom_line but keep the dots closer together. The R code below produces a basic reproducible example of what I see, and then I include another chart showing what I would like to see.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(5223)
myDF <- data.frame(x=rnorm(20,0,1),
                   y=runif(20,0,20))
myDF <- myDF %>% 
  mutate(From8to12 = y>=8 & y<=12)

ggplot(myDF,aes(x=x,y=y,col=From8to12)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(yintercept=8,lty="dotted") +
  geom_hline(yintercept=12,lty="dotted",size=1.5)
```

## Unedited Image

[image: Unedited image]

## (Manually) Edited Image (In Paint)

I would like to make the dots bigger, but closer together. Is this possible? I've found nothing online.

[image: Edited Image]

Comment: I don't know if there is a nice way to do it but maybe you would prefer a [different linetype](http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/linetype)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's something like `lty` in base R plot, and one way is to specify specifically how long should the dash and gap be:

```
ggplot(myDF,aes(x=x,y=y,col=From8to12)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_hline(yintercept=8,lty="dotted") +
  geom_hline(yintercept=12,lty="11",size=1.5)
```

the "11" means length of 1 for dash, length of 1 for gap, and it will replicate this. you can see more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788945/how-to-define-more-line-types-for-graphs-in-r)

[image]

Comment: Wonderful! I love the intricacies of R. Thank you for this!

Comment: That's pretty nice. Learned something new

Comment: I appreciate this answer so much!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**
I thought it wasn't possible without some severe hacking of the underlying draw functions - @StupidWolf's [answer proved me wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60282293/7941188). My suggestion was to draw every single point with `geom_point` and `shape = 15` (filled square). It is then a matter of your final plot size, what parameters you chose (i.e., the distance between the 'dots' and their size)

P.S. It's impressive that you have actually managed to produce your image in paint.

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(5223)
myDF <- data.frame(x = rnorm(20, 0, 1), y = runif(20, 0, 20))

dot_dis <- 0.05
x_line <- seq(min(myDF$x), max(myDF$x), dot_dis)
y_line <- 12

ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x, y), data = myDF) +
  geom_point(aes(x_line, y_line), shape = 15, size = 1.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Editing the image in paint took about 10 minutes. I zoomed in on the line, and reduced the number of pixels between each square. Some quick drag and drop, then some copy and paste, redraw the white lines, and voila!