# customize the line types in chart R ggplot? My problem involves plotting 10 categories in a black and white chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, customization, linechart

I am not referring to the standard options of solid, dotted, dashed, etc. I would like to create custom line types such as (..--..--..) and (---...---...---).

Please find the code I have developed till now and the graph I have generated below. Please note that I have 10 sub-datasets which I am using to generate a combined line chart.

```
ggplot() +  
geom_line(data = datav2_MH, aes(x = date, y = MH, linetype = "MH"),
          colour = "black",  size = 1, group = 1) +
geom_line(data = datav2_AP, aes(x = date, y = AP, linetype = "AP"),
          colour = "black", size = 1, group = 1) +
geom_line(data = datav2_TN, aes(x = date, y = TN, linetype = "TN"),
          colour = "black", size = 1, group = 1) +
geom_line(data = datav2_KN, aes(x = date, y = KN, linetype = "KN"),
          colour = "black", size = 1, group = 1) +
geom_line(data = datav2_UP, aes(x = date, y = UP, linetype = "UP"),
          colour = "black", size = 1, group = 1) +
geom_line(data = datav2_DL, aes(x = date, y = DL, linetype = "DL"),
          colour = "grey", size = 1, group = 1) +
geom_line(data = datav2_WB, aes(x = date, y = WB, linetype = "WB"),
          colour = "grey", size = 1, group = 1) +
geom_line(data = datav2_KR, aes(x = date, y = KR, linetype = "KR"),
          colour = "grey", size = 1, group = 1) +
geom_line(data = datav2_OD, aes(x = date, y = OD, linetype = "OD"),
          colour = "grey", size = 1, group = 1) +
geom_line(data = datav2_RJ, aes(x = date, y = RJ, linetype = "RJ"),
          colour = "grey", size = 1, group = 1) +
guides(fill = guide_legend(keywidth = 1, keyheight = 1),
          linetype=guide_legend(keywidth = 2.5, keyheight = 1))+
  
scale_linetype_manual(values = c(
    'MH' = 1, "AP" = 2, "TN" = 3,
    "KN" = 4, 'UP' = 5, "DL" = 6,
    "WB" = 1, 'KR' = 2,
    "OD" = 3, "RJ" = 4))+

geom_dl(data = datav2_MH, aes(x = date, y = MH, label = "MH"), method = "top.qp", cex = 0.2) +
geom_dl(data = datav2_AP, aes(x = date, y = AP, label = "AP"), method = "top.qp", cex = 0.2) +
geom_dl(data = datav2_TN, aes(x = date, y = TN, label = "TN"), method = "top.qp", cex = 0.2) +
geom_dl(data = datav2_KN, aes(x = date, y = KN, label = "KN"), method = "top.qp", cex = 0.2) +
geom_dl(data = datav2_DL, aes(x = date, y = DL, label = "DL"), method = "top.qp", cex = 0.2) +
geom_dl(data = datav2_UP, aes(x = date, y = UP, label = "UP"), method = "top.qp", cex = 0.2) +
geom_dl(data = datav2_WB, aes(x = date, y = WB, label = "WB"), method = "top.qp", cex = 0.2) +
geom_dl(data = datav2_KR, aes(x = date, y = KR, label = "KR"), method = "top.qp", cex = 0.2) +
geom_dl(data = datav2_OD, aes(x = date, y = OD, label = "OD"), method = "top.qp", cex = 0.2) +
geom_dl(data = datav2_RJ, aes(x = date, y = RJ, label = "RJ"), method = "top.qp", cex = 0.2) +

theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,1),"cm")) +
  xlab("Date") +
  ylab("Total_Confirmed_Cases") +
  scale_y_continuous() +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("2020-03-31", "2020-04-30", "2020-05-31", "2020-06-30",
    "2020-07-31", "2020-08-31", "2020-09-30", "2020-10-31", "2020-11-30", "2020-12-31",
    "2021-01-31")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[The chart containing a line for 10 states. The data is at a daily level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz24B.png)

Comment: Please click on the hyperlink "The chart containing a line for 10 states. The data is at a daily level to view the graph

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to define more line types for graphs in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788945/how-to-define-more-line-types-for-graphs-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manually specify linetypes, you can do this with `scale_linetype_manual()`. For the `values` argument, you can give a character vector with an even number of (hexadecimal) numbers. The first number is for the dash-length, the second number is the gap-length. For example `"1234"` will give a size 1 dash, a size 2 gap, a size 3 dash and a size 4 gap, which will repeat. For brevity, I use different data in the example below.

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.0.3
df <- DNase[!duplicated(DNase[, c("Run", "conc")]),]

ggplot(df, aes(conc, density, linetype = Run)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c(
    "12", "34", "41", "F2", "11", "21",
    "1141", "2134", "7171", "1717", "4243"
  ))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This solves a big part of my problem.

Comment: There is another question that I have, I would like to change the color of some of the lines to grey. If I change the color of specific states in the geom_line(), the graph shows updated colors but the colors in the legends are all black.

Comment: Yeah if you leave the colour outside the `aes()` it doesn't show up in the legend. If you do `aes(..., colour = "the_same_as_linetype")` they should form a common legend. Then you just have to set the right colours in `scale_colour_manual(values = c("black", "black", "grey", ...))`.

Comment: A new problem occurs if I use scale_colour_manual in combination with scale_linetype_manual : there appear two separate sets of legends which don't fit into the graph

Comment: They need to have the same titles, breaks, labels and such

Comment: Sorry, i have kept everything same but still 2 different sets of legends appear

Comment: geom_line(data = datav2_MH, aes(x = date, y = MH, linetype = "MH", colour = "MH"), size = 1, group = 1)+...+
scale_color_manual(values = c(
    'MH' = 'black', ... 
scale_linetype_manual(values = c(
    'MH' = "12", ...

Comment: Yes that is how you should do it. Can you attach a picture to your question?

Comment: Apologies I am new to posting questions on stackoverflow. I am not able to paste a screenshot in the comment. Please guide me if possible

Comment: I have added the picture as another answer to this question. Please confirm if you are able to view it

Comment: Yes I can see it. I think it might be the titles for the scales, can you set `scale_linetype_manual(..., name = "abc")` and `scale_colour_manual(..., name = "abc")` and see if it helps?

Comment: sorry, do you mean change "MH" to "abc", for example?

Comment: No the `name` argument in the scale. The scales must be very similar in terms of titles, breaks, labels in order for the legends to combine.

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks a ton for your guidance and time spent